# Unable to install a new JasperReports runtime on Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'd like to compile my reports with earlier versions of the JasperReports, so I'm trying to add other versions of the JasperReports to my Jaspersoft Studio on: *Project -> Properties -> Jaspersoft Studio -> Compatibility -> Use Project Settings -> Manage JasperReports Version*.

I choose the *Add From URL* option and then I select some version on combobox. After a few moments I get the error below:

[image]

I tried to install many versions but all of them failed.

I'm opening the Jaspersoft Studio with admin privilegies on Windows and my environment is as follows:

- Windows 7
- Java 8
- Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.0

Note: I've already tried with Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1 too.

I'd like to know if this is a problem of my environment. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Did you try to clean this folder manually?

Comment: @AlexK Yes, I did. Manually the file is deleted with success.

Comment: Is the problem is gone?

Comment: I'm sorry for not saying, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Don't fight the problem, workaround it*

I also have had some problems like "handsake-failure" ecc, trying to use url system to download, unzip and install older versions.

**Blaarg, lets install it by hand.**

1. Download the version you like from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/archive/jasperreports/), for example 
   [5.6.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%205.6.1/jasperreports-5.6.1-project.zip/download)
2. Unzip it
3. Press <kbd>Add From Path</kbd> and select the jasper-reports folder[image: JasperSoftStudio]

Ok, Ok and your problem should be solved, basically this way your are eliminating all problems related to download and unzipping the project.

If you like you can open an issue on the [jasper-reports bugs tracker](http://community.jaspersoft.com/bug-tracker), but in the mean while you are up and running

Comment: link for download older version: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/archive/jasperreports/
link for recent version: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/